# gerrit setup for my git server

Tags: git, project, clone, gerrit

I have around 10 git repos on remote server and now i want to setup gerrit for the code t review. Can some one give brief steps on how to configure gerrit project.

I have set it up gerrit and the site is displayed properly with no projects listed in Admin.

What is the next step to import my 10 projects onto gerrit and how to submit review uploads into gerrit.. what exactly the project name i need to create/clone.. what user i need to use while cloning/pushing.. wht path i need to use..

here are my details. I have looked all google sites but not able to find how to start using gerrit..

gerrit installed -- /home/gerrit2/review_site
gerrit installed with user  -- gerrit
all my 10 git projects installed - /home/repos/
10 repos created with user on remote --  web

appreciate for earlier responses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't import projects into Gerrit.  You point it to your git repos and it operates directly on them.

I'd look at the log file for gerrit to see if it's complaining about any paths or anything.

One tip: for us, /etc/default/gerritcodereview is sourced by test_site/bin/gerrit.sh. In it, we set the umask to '2' so that files and directories created by gerrit will be group-writable.  This is important if you have different users using gerrit, which is the whole point.